# Constant of motion in a high dimensional analogue of the Lotka-Volterra system.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Suppose I would extend the Lotka Volterra system to the the $n$-dim first order ODE

\begin{eqnarray*}
\dot{x}_{1} &=& x_1(x_2-\alpha_1)   \\
\dot{x}_{2} &=& x_2(x_3-\alpha_2)   \\
 \vdots  \; \;  &=&  \; \; \vdots \\ 
\dot{x}_{n}  &=&  x_n(x_1-\alpha_n)   
\end{eqnarray*}

where $\alpha_i$ are constants and $n \geq 2$. Note that for $n=2$ we get the Lotka Volterra system upto a scaling. In the sense of Lotka-Volterra the above model is a  population model for $n$-different species where the population of each species depends on one other and where finally the last is coupled back to the first.

For $n=2$ finding the constant of motion  ( a non-trivial function $f$ such that for all solution curves $x$ we have that $f(x)=$ constant) is straightforward. However, I am not completely sure how to to this for the $n$-dimension case or if it even exists. Any help is welcome!

Comment: What do you mean by the constant of motion?

Comment: @Amzoti Problem has been updated

Comment: For the $n=2$ case, can you please state what the solution (constant of motion) is?

Comment: @Amzoti $f(x_1,x_2)=\mathrm e^{x_2-x_1}|x_1|^{\alpha_2}|x_2|^{-\alpha_1}$.